# replacing special characters in between the multiple substring in a string

Tags: python

Consider a string:

```
str1="abcd<aaa>some thing <#^&*some more!#$@ </aaa> 
                            abcdefgasf <aaa>asfaf %^&*$saf  asf %$^ </aaa>
                            <another tag> some text </another tag>
                            <aaa>sfafaff#%%%^^</aaa> "
```

Now in the above string how to replace the special characters and white spaces that are present between the tag `<aaa>` and `</aaa>`?

The replacing character should be '_'.

Comment: expected result : "abcd<aaa>some thing _____some more____ </aaa> 
                            abcdefgasf <aaa>asfaf _____saf  asf ___ </aaa>
                            <another tag> some text </another tag>
                            <aaa>sfafaff______</aaa> "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution, is a little bit complex, so I'll explain it step by step.

We are going to use a module called `re`, for regular expressions:

```
import re
```

OK, here is our string:

```
s = 'abcd<aaa>some thing <#^&*some more!#$@ </aaa> abcdefgasf <aaa>asfaf %^&*$saf  asf %$^ </aaa> <another tag> some text </another tag> <aaa>sfafaff#%%%^^</aaa>'
```

First, let's get all the content inside the tags:

```
inside_tags = re.findall('<aaa>(.+?)</aaa>', s)
```

Now, lets iterate through each content of `inside_tags` and replace the special characters:

```
cleaned_contents = [ re.sub('[^\w ]', '_' , content) for content in inside_tags ]
```

So, in `cleaned_contents` now we have the contents inside the tags, but with the special characters replaced. Now, lets `zip` (join in a tuple) each content inside a tag with its "cleaned" content:

```
zipped = zip(inside_tags, cleaned_contents)
```

And finally, search the tag contents in the string and replace them with the new cleaned content:

```
for old, new in zipped:
    s = s.replace(old, new)
```

**NOTE:** If you don't understand something (there is a bunch of weird stuff here, like `?`, `[^\w ]`, `zip`) post your comment below and I'll explain it.

Comment: @jaganath if this answer solved your problem, you could choose it as your accepted answer (same for your other question)

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to split up the string around the tags (you can used re.split() if the string is well-behaved, otherwise use an XML parser); then you can use re.sub() to replace the characters you want replaced.

Comment: when i used the xml parser it throwed an error because it cannot parse  the charecters that are not supported in html tags